# A modified variable does not change the value in update() method in Unity5

Tags: unity-game-engine

I declared a variable in a script:

```
private int count;
```

Init it at `Awake()` method:

```
void Awake() 
{
    count = 1;
}
```

Keep checking an print the value of it:

```
void Update ()
{
    Debug.Log(count);
}
```

Then declared a method to change the value of this variable:

```
public void ChangeValue()
{
    count = 2;
    Debug.Log("button has being pressed!");
    Debug.Log(count);
}
```

Then create a button to call this method to change the value, the value that print out in update() method does not change without any error.

Here is the log:

[image: Picture of Unity console, showing debug output]

No matter how many times I pressed the button, the count variable in `Update()` method is still "1".

How can I update the variable value inside the `Update()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is either attached to the-same GameObject twice or attached to multiple  GameObjects. The images below shows how to easily find out and fix it for each scenario.

Your script is attached to the-same GameObject more than once:

[image]

Your script is attached to multiple GameObjects:

[image]

---

That should solve your problem. If not then it's a comibation of this and *Collapse* is enabled. So you must also disable *Collapse* too as [Ariss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44688855/3785314) mentioned.

[image]

Comment: Did you really intend to embed that same gif twice?

Comment: Nope. It was a typo in the first link.

Comment: Problom SOLVED! Thank you so much! I attached the script  to multiple GameObjects by misstake. @Programmer

Comment: Nice. Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) my answer to mark it as solved.

Comment: is it just pitching on the tick on the left side of you answer?@Programmer

Comment: What do you mean by "pitching"? You did it right. You ticked the answer as correct/helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have your log set to **collapse**, which groups together the same items being logged, it looks like you already are achieving the affect you wanted where it is printing 2.

Comment: This is at least *plausible,* given the nature of the collapsed logs.

Comment: but the upate() still keep print count value as "1" times and times again, it still using the "old" value.

Comment: can you upload your full script to hastebin.com @waynelee, it provide more information

Comment: Not just in the log, when I do some conditional judgment base on the count value in update() method, It's still the wrong value.