# Variable change is not persisted in Update Function in Unity3d using Unity Events

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Invoke Unity Events to detect whether a user presses or holds a button. I can see the function firing, and I'm setting `respawnHeld` to true. Yet Update always logs it as false. I'm completely at a loss here....I can't see what could possibly be setting `respawnHeld` back to false.

```
    private bool respawnHeld;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log($"In Update Function RespawnHeld is {respawnHeld}");
    }

    public void RespawnInput(InputAction.CallbackContext callbackContext)
    {
        Debug.Log("SETTING RESPAWN HELD TO TRUE");
        respawnHeld = true;
        Debug.Log($"In RespawnInput Function RespawnHeld is {respawnHeld}");
    }
```

After pressing my key 'R'. I would expect to see logs stating "In Update Function RespawnHeld is True". However the logs I'm getting are as follows:

[image]

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A modified variable does not change the value in update() method in Unity5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688829/a-modified-variable-does-not-change-the-value-in-update-method-in-unity5)

Comment: Unfortunately not :( This is the only instance of the script in the scene. I've also tried with log collapse on/off with no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't say with certainty what fixed this. But in my case the caller of Respawn Input is a Unity Event (from the input system). I removed the script from my Game Object, then reconfigured all my events and it works now.
[image]